# List of privileges and their reputation caps

Tags: support, reputation

I couldn't figure out how to search this so:

Is there a list of all the privileges and their reputation caps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clicking on the trophy symbol in the upper right hand corner of the site opens a menu that shows your reputation/badge/privilege gains and in the top right corner of that menu you find the hyperlink to the help center entry about privileges. It also contains a link to the badges that are available.

[List of privileges](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

[List of badges](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges)